# Cannot 'enable mobile broadband' even after checking it

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, network-manager

Is the network manager in Oneiric different from Natty? How can I get the old one back ? Or is it the problem with some packages ? I used to connect to internet using my mobile broadband device using one click. Now I've to remove, replug, restart atleast 10 times to connect it.

Since you've asked, I'm using Natty and Oneiric with the same /home partition with the same username. So, it's a fresh install of Oneiric not an upgrade. The same problem appeared with the live cd and while installing Oneiric.

Also, even after I enable mobile broadband ( below enable networking, wireless) , when I click on the mobile connection and it tries to connect, it displays as 'not enabled'.

Comment: I cannot see any change. Everything works as used to work in natty! Did you do an upgrade? Have you tried reinstall it?

Comment: @Stefano reinstall what?

Comment: The network manager package from Synaptic (Yes I still use it :))

Comment: I have the same problem with all ubuntu versions (for my phone only other phones working finly)
so i am using wvdial .it partialy solved my problem

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention how you installed/upgraded, so I'll go on a limb and say you upgraded, from what you describe. Until you add more info, I'll just answer your question directly.

It is not "the same" in the sense that it is a newer version. Some things have changed, but you should be able to connect to what you used to as normal. Ensure that your networks are not using ipv6 unless they need to.

Comment: I've done a fresh install using the same /home using the same username. So I've both Oneiric and Natty sharing the same /home partition. Is that causing the problem ?

Comment: But I found the same problem with the live cd as well, so I guess the partition is not the problem, something to do with the connection manager.

Comment: Can you explain in steps how to disable ipv6 ?

Comment: @amithviswanath: click edit connections, chose the connection you want to edit, and then from the ipv6 tab choose ignore (as opposed to automatic for example).

Comment: No, it doesn't have a ipv6 tab. So it's not the problem I guess, also even after I enable mobile broadband it displays not enabled.

Comment: @amithviswanath: you should report a bug.

Comment: I have same problem with all ubuntu distros while using my phone but no problem with another phone

but wvdial works for me but it wont support software centre completly